# Is this php behaviour explained somewhere in manual? (strings with zeroes comparison)

Tags: php

Why for php

```
'00' == '0000'
```

expression is `true`?

Is it explained somewhere in manual?

**NOTE**:

this:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically

isn't suitable for the case, both operands are strings.

Comment: Heck, I  still can't get WHY we're doing so. To see if string is numeric - then cast - and then compare. Why can't we just compare '00' to '0' the same way we're doing it for '00s' and '0s'?

Comment: Well, finally found out, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16880342/285587

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically." ([PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))

Comment: "or the comparison involves numerical strings" --- oh, I missed that, right. I was inattentive, and will mark this answer after 15 minutes timeout.

Answer (score 3):

Sure

```
== compares values and neglects type
=== compares values and types
```

here is it:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

***UPDATE:**

Read this part in this URL :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting
>   apply.

Comment: value of the string `'00'` isn't equal to value of the string `'0000'`, like string `'a'` isn't equal to string `'b'`

Comment: @zerkms Numeric-looking strings get turned into numbers by PHP.

Comment: any string that is all composed of numbers will be converted to numbers in comparison (on the left side of course)

Comment: @Shehabox: I asked the exact explanation "why"

Comment: "Try this :" --- omg, I asked a quote from manual, not another examples.

Comment: @zerkms Oh ok I got what you mean yes it's in the manualy, I'll point you to it shortly..

Comment: @Shehabox: the link to the whole section isn't what I asked. If you look at the question you'll see I've read that but missed several words (this is what confused me)

Comment: `intval` is completely irrelevant to the question

Comment: @Shehabox: "automatically" because of what? My question was - why the strings are compared as numbers.

Comment: @Shehabox: I know how it's called. The question was: **why** it happens (in this case), not how it happens. You see the difference?

Comment: Well, This is PHP :D, that's why there is double == and triple ===

Comment: If I was the creator of it, I wouldn't force such conversion but it's just made like that to make it easier for some people, and they made the triple equal operator to avoid that if needed.

Comment: @Shehabox: not an explanation. See the checked answer

Comment: You're missing the whole point of the question. This behaviour is **documented**, and "Well, This is PHP" isn't an explanation in any way.

Comment: I pointed you already to this part in the document from the beginning "Where is it in the documentation"

Comment: @Shehabox: I don't see that

Comment: @Shehabox: a link to the whole section isn't a good reference. You could give http://google.com link as well - I'm sure it also has an answer *somewhere*

Comment: @Shehabox: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php takes 5 screen of text on my laptop. It's only 4 lines if you know where to read. I was inattentive at my first read of that section (before question), so the same link to the same section isn't helpful at all.

Comment: I'm talking about the description below the main paragraph, at least this how I always refer to the manual.

Comment: Anyway, I was just trying to help, I really don't put in mind or care about points in here :D

Answer (score 2):

Because when you compare this strings they become zeros on both sides so 0 == 0 is true, try to use `'00' === '0000'` [here is link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: "If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically" from link which i posted

Comment: @zerkms The explanation is in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just read:

> If [...] the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically

I removed the part that probably was standing in your way.

Answer (score 0):

It's also good to remember that

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is === or !== as this involves comparing the type as well as the value. [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

But everything everyone else has said is correct!