# How can comparing string to zero be true?

Tags: php

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump("some" == 0);
bool(true)
php > var_dump("some" == false);
bool(false)
php > var_dump("some" == true);
bool(true)
php > var_dump(false == 0);
bool(true)
```

My question is simple. What is the reasoning behind `("some" == 0) === true`? I understand that due to the weak typing the operands are converted to something comparable. But in this particular example it's against how I understand it.

If the zero would be converted to string it would be:

```
php > var_dump("some" == "0");
bool(false)
```

If it was converted to bool, it would be:

```
php > var_dump("some" == false);
bool(false)
```

Only sensible explanation is:

```
php > var_dump(intval("some"));
int(0)
php > var_dump(intval("some") == 0);
bool(true)
```

But that's certainly not what I or anyone would expect. Especially because **any string would be turned to zero** (and that potentially means false in any comparison).

Why is it this way?

**Update:**

My question was more about "why" not "if" or "how", sorry if that was not quite obvious. And I think I found my answer in [Why PHP casts two numerical strings to numbers before [loosely] comparing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16880295/112000)

Comment: Have you tried to read manual? http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: Loose typing [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples

```
php > var_dump("some" == 0);
```

The string "some" is cast to an integer for comparison with an integer, and will be cast to a `0` in this case.

`0 == 0` is true

If the string "13 monkeys" was cast to an integer, it would be a value of `13`

```
php > var_dump("13monkeys" == 0);
```

`13 == 0` is false

The rules for casting a string to a number are explained in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)